# Как установить 3G модем в Knoppix LiveCD ?

Tags: железо

Модем Huawei E1750. от Мегафона, разлоченный. Там даже есть что-то типа дров или софта для Linux. Вот только не знаю что с этим делать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, подробно...

Comment: Используйте полноценный современный дистр., а не LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

При подключении должно появляться несколько последовательных портов,один из них работает наподобие модема с AT-командами, через него создаётся соединение.Сначала попробуйте подключиться через minicom.